# How can I store password in my IOT device so I can connect again? And how can store multiple wifi credentials so i can make it portable as well?

Tags: android, wifi, iot

I have an device which is connected to the WiFi using an android device. But i am not sure how to reconnect this device when the device gets disconnected.

So the use cases i am looking at is:

1. How to store WiFi credentials in my device such that it
   auto-connects ?
2. Also how to store multiple WiFi credentials so i can store WiFi and move my device across to different places?

Comment: Which OS are you using? Android or Windows? Both should store WiFi passwords and use them if possible.... so where is the problem?

Comment: The device i am talking about is a headless device which runs on linux OS. Can you share moire details how to achieve this? Thanks a ton Nico